# Naming Convention in C#.Net Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, console-application, naming-conventions

I am beginner in C#. Can anyone please help me to know about the naming convention in c#?
I have searched on Google but I didn't find the suitable answer. So please tell me about the naming convention of C#.

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This link was helpful for me when i started with c#: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards